# Best way to organize editable internal data files for Android app?

Tags: android

I want to use data from an xml file to populate AutoCompleteTextViews and MultiAutoCompleteTextViews, and I also want to be able to edit this file while the app is running so that the AutoCompleteTextViews can be updated with new information. What is the best way to go about this? I know that files in the /res folder cannot be written to during runtime, and writing to external storage is slower than accessing internal storage.

Comment: If you're concerned about speed of external storage access, why don't you just copy the files to the internal storage `/files` directory?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is by creating your own SQLite database.

I would make sure that the scope of what you are doing merits a database, though.

The other option is just to create a flat file with keyValuePairs and look up the value with the view's ID as the key.  This could be stored in external storage.  Access speed should not be a big concern for a text file.